# use facet grid for x axis not aes in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to create a ggplot facet grid where the x axis of the grid (not the plot) are the labels, rather than squish into each chartlet.

Example:

```
mtcars %>% 
  group_by(mpg) %>% 
  mutate(cnt = n()) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = cyl, y = cnt)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  facet_grid(vs ~ cyl)
```

Looks like:
[image]

Rather than having 3 through 9 on each individual chart, I would like the horizontal part of the grid to be cyl as opposed to each individual chart.

In other words, each bar chart should be a single column bar chart only.

How can I do this?

Comment: You want to turn off x labels or not faceting?

Comment: Please see updated / edited post. I'm seeking to make it so that each chart in the picture is just a single column bar chart. There's only one column anyway on each, but I had to include aes(x = cyl) just to get it to run

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a constant for the x value, while still faceting by cyl:

```
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>% 
  group_by(mpg) %>% 
  mutate(cnt = n()) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = 1, y = cnt)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  facet_grid(vs ~ cyl) + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank()) + 
  labs(x = "cyl")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
mtcars %>% 
  group_by(mpg) %>% 
  mutate(cnt = n()) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = cyl, y = cnt)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  facet_grid(vs ~ cyl)+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(),axis.ticks = element_blank())
```

[image]

Or like this?

```
mtcars %>% 
  group_by(mpg) %>% 
  mutate(cnt = n()) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = cyl, y = cnt)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  facet_grid(vs ~ cyl, scales="free")+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(),axis.ticks = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for attempting to help me but Jordo's answer is what I needed